# Community Wiki, where is it?

Tags: discussion, questions, chat, community-wiki, featured-questions

I understand that, in theory, a community wiki exists. I also understand that the term "wiki" may have a somewhat fluid definition. None-the-less, I'm thinking that questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python) would be really great to alter somewhat and include on a wiki of the Wikipedia-style-wiki.

If such a thing exists, I cannot find it. I know this is a noob question, but

1. Where is the wiki?
2. Is it a Wikipedia-style wiki, or what sort of wiki are we talking about here?

**Bonus question**: How the heck do you access the chat?

Comment: ↓ Down there in the footer is a link to the chat

Comment: A community wiki is a post that is able to be maintained by community with less work and does not provide reputation gains to the author. It is not intended to create broad open ended questions like the one you linked. Here is the help center article on it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki

Comment: Is it possible to access all wiki questions somewhere?

Comment: Community Wiki on stackoverflow is really just a question that can be edited by a larger number of users. It isn't a separate portion of the site, and questions still have to follow the rules.

Comment: @KevinB Well... that's a misleading term. Thanks for the answer! (if you wanted to make that an answer, I would choose it).

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner How is it misleading at all?  Something being a wiki implied how it's edited, not what that content is.  That's not an unusual interpretation.

Comment: @Servy I dunno, I just googled `define wiki` and it said "a website that allows collaborative editing of its content and structure by its users." Emphasis on the "and structure."

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner And that applies here, just within the content of a single post, rather than an entire site.

Comment: @Servy I'm not so sure about that, it kind of seems to me that editing the "structure" of a post isn't sufficient to make bring it within the definition of a wiki. But really, who cares? It is what it is. The point is that there is no wikimedia-type-wiki.

Comment: @Servy: the term is misleading because it isn't a separate site or tree (e.g. wiki.stackoverflow.com), only a category of question and answer, mixed in with the others. Every other wiki I've ever seen was. Personally I would have called it "community-editable question/answer"

Comment: @smci *All* answers on the site are community editable.  A community wiki answer simply has more lax requirements on what type of edits are allowed and lower requirements on making them without review.  But *all* posts still allow certain types of editing.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Community Wiki on Stack Overflow is really just a question or answer that can be edited by a larger number of users. It isn't a separate portion of the site, and they still have to follow the rules.

The question you linked to wouldn't be a very good candidate for a community wiki.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki

(this answer is a community wiki)

Comment: Should also note that a Community Wiki don't give/take rep when it's up/down voted

Comment: Thought about adding that, but concluded it wasn't important to the question.

Comment: @Memor-X: no rep for the one who adds the answer and marks it as wiki or no rep for the ones who edit it afterwards?

Comment: @Crick3t Neither. I don't remember if the OP gets to keep any rep they had gained from the post before it was made wiki.

Comment: @KevinB, I think it's very important that people don't get reputation anymore for cw questions, and this is the worst part actually. By the way, I never edited my answer, not even once, but still my answer converted to cw. Now I can't gain repution. If my answer never updated, then why I'm not gaining reputation when people upvote it? I would vote for stopping this future (cw questions/answers) actually. Can we make voting for stopping this future? Preventing the author from reputation is not the right solution, there must be better solution for that.

Answer (score 15):

A control exists under the answer editor that allows to post an answer as a community wiki directly:

> [image: community wiki checkbox]

For example, when this answer was posted that checkbox was checked, which means this is now a community wiky, editable by the community at large.

Comment: Upvote for the freehand circle :)

Comment: How to make a question community wiki?

Comment: @user541396 Become a moderator.

Comment: @Servy I found that the privilege to make an answer community wiki "Awarded at: 10 reputation" https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki Where did you find about making the question community wiki?

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko You could...read the comment I posted stating the answer?  That's kinda all there is to it, really.

Comment: @Servy which answer do you mean? I was wondering about community question, not answer.

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310947/community-wiki-where-is-it/380867?noredirect=1#comment760021_380867

Comment: @Servy this comment I read (otherwise I wouldn't ask), but didn't think that is a definite reference.

Comment: @YaroslavNikitenko If you don't want to believe me then that's your choice.  You have my answer, what you want to do with it is up to yo.