# Please rename "wiki"

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, community-wiki, terminology

The term *wiki* has a reasonably well-understood definition.  To help newcomers to Stack Overflow find their way around the site, we should avoid using this term inappropriately.

Hence, I propose renaming these two concepts in the Stack Overflow user interface:

- "tag wiki" -> "tag information"
- "community wiki" -> "community owned"

Paraphrasing [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki#Characteristics), a wiki is a system which allows visitors to edit *and create* pages and links between them freely (emphasis mine).  As a former/casual user of proper wikis like [c2](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WelcomeVisitors), [MeatBallWiki](http://meatballwiki.org/wiki/action=browse&id=MeatballProject), [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/) etc. and of course [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/) that is the behavior I would expect, but it is not the behavior of anything called "wiki" on StackOverflow.

On Stack Overflow, the concept of a "tag wiki" is married to Stack Overflow tags: A "wiki" page cannot exist unless the tag it corresponds with also exists; there are no "wiki" pages which are not also "tag wiki" pages.

Adding to the confusion, there are questions and answers which are assigned "community wiki" status, but they do not exist outside of the context of the question where they are posted; they are just a "community ownership" tag, with no particular meaning attached to the "wiki" part of the term.

This mixing of terms is unfortunate and misleading, and leads to misunderstandings such as this one:  [Community Wiki, where is it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310947/community-wiki-where-is-it)

The two "wiki" concepts are completely unrelated; there is basically nothing in common between "tag wiki" and "community wiki".  The "wiki" part of the name is unhelpful for newcomers who try to understand how these parts fit together, and by and large ignored by those who have already figured it out.

I see no reason to stick to the "wiki" terminology here. If "tag information" is unsuitable, perhaps "tag details" could be acceptable?  Similarly, "community owned" could be even just "community" or "community content".  The beef here is, removing the misleading part of the name should add clarity.

As programmers, I would expect and assume everyone here to be sensitive to the importance of naming things. We don't call a "heap" a "stack" or vice versa. If a user interface element has [a legend which you must google in order to understand what it does](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts), it might just as well be labeled with a unique but meaningless string.

I understand there may be a (pre-?) historic reason these names were originally coined using this terminology, but if this link once existed, it is not properly documented, and if anything, hampers transparency.

Comment: I don't really see any confusion regarding "wiki", but maybe that's just me.

Comment: @DonkeyKong If you can explain what it means, please do. Maybe I'm wrong. What information does it add, and why is using an existing word with another meaning useful, or at least a reasonable compromise somehow?

Comment: Complaining about it isn't very constructive, just recommend a better term and if everybody likes it then it will stick.

Comment: @HansPassant do you disagree with the proposal for "tag information" and "community owned"?

Comment: You mean you want to use those words instead of "wiki"?  Keep trying.

Comment: @HansPassant I was hoping you had simply missed the fact that I was in fact not *merely* complaining. If you don't like those proposed replacements, I'm not fanatically committed to those precise phrases, but would appreciate any similarly constructive discussion for what requirements we would like to see for replacement terms.

Comment: I'm not convinced a problem exists. Do you have any evidence for it?

Comment: @bjb568 I linked to an example question as evidence already in the first version of my question. I'm sure other examples could be brought up if you don't think that is sufficient, but I am primarily concerned with the understanding of newcomers who are probably somewhat unlikely to document this source of possible confusion even if they are affected.

Comment: One confused newcomer? That's not very convincing that there's a problem.

Comment: The problem with your suggested new terms is that nothing about them implies that any user can edit those the way the term "[blah] wiki] does.

Comment: @BSMP Thanks for bringing that up. I'll try to think of better terms.

Comment: This would kill two birds with one stone, too: once the tag wikis are no longer called "wiki"s, there's no reason to [upgrade them to allow linking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122197/tag-wikis-need-a-size-and-functionality-increase)!

Comment: @JoshCaswell You're saying it as if it were a good thing. I would regard the linked question as additional proof that the thing is broken, only I'm too jaded to think the disappointing lack of actual wiki functionality could ever be fixed; and so I'm suggesting to instead lower the expectations for new visitors.

Comment: Sorry, forgot my <cynical> tag in that comment. I think this proposal of yours makes sense, in the context of tag wikis never getting upgraded (which I too would prefer to the rename).

Comment: I guess in the long term wiki is going to be deprecated in favor of Documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that our Stack Overlords basically agreed with me after all; this is now by and large [status-completed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) (though [a small band of rebels still engages in daring missions of resistance)](/questions/362748/tag-info-page-revision-page-still-links-back-to-wiki#comment553416_362748).

Because this *looks like* it never went anywhere, I am posting this as a self-answer.

Answer (score 2):

My two cents: you may want to read up on the [origin and etymology of the word "wiki (wiki)"](http://c2.com/doc/etymology.html).

It just became to mean "collaboratively editable webpage", stretchable to any means imaginable. The whole concept of "pages", "links" and "structure" came later and are more specific to Wikipedia's encyclopedia style, which are in my opinion not a prerequisite for calling something a "wiki".

Comment: I am well familiar with the etymology, and I don't think the resource you link to really conflicts with anything in my question. Stack Overflow is of course entitled to using the term any way we like, but giving it a nonstandard Stack-only connotation is shooting ourselves in the foot. To me, and clearly to the user whose question I linked to, stretching the meaning beyond the common usage, as documented on Wikipedia, is confusing and counter-productive.

Comment: For historical context, I would instead propose the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_wikis#CamelCase_and_internal_links (good anchor for the immediate reference, but maybe start reading a little above the anchor). My own experience dates back to 2003-2004 approx which is arguably when the concept began to pick up traction; by that time, interlinking wiki pages was a well-established, if not defining, convention.