# Tag info page revision history page still links back to "wiki"

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, user-interface

When looking at e.g. [the history for the `make` tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3624982/revisions) it displays the headline **Return to the makefile wiki**. My impression is that this terminology is now obsolete and should be replaced with something like *Return to the makefile tag info page*.

[image: Screen shot for illustration]

The [excerpt history page](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3624983/revisions) has a similarly labelled link at the top as well.

Unfortunately, I have not seen an official position on this, but I have observed that many other places which used to refer to this as a "tag wiki" now use different terminology [(which is IMHO a good thing)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318084/please-rename-wiki).

Comment: I'll notice that the Meta tag name [meta-tag:tag-wiki] also remains a reference to what appears to be obsolescent terminology.

Comment: The help center shows no indication the term is deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=Tag+wiki

Comment: Looking through Meta.SE, the help center and the tag wiki UI I see no evidence that tag wikis a re now being referred to by different terminology. Editing a tag wiki has a big help box on the right that uses the terminology throughout, for example.  What evidence do you have?

Comment: Mainly the UI elements around the tag info page. When you [visit a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile), the links say "improve tag info", where it used to say "improve tag wiki" (or something along those lines). On the tag info page, it says "Edit Tag Info" on the button where IIRC it used to say "Edit Tag Wiki".

Comment: Given that almost everywhere else, including the editing UI, still says ‘tag wiki’ I’m inclinded to say that this bug report is *at the very least* premature.